# How to deseriealize XML items as different objects?

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I am receving an XML from a 3rd party with this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ColorPages version="1">
                <Page PrintedPagePosition="0" PDFPagePosition="0" IsColor="True" />
                <Ghost PrintedPagePosition="1" PDFPagePosition="1" MayBePrinted="Unprinted" IsColor="False" />
                <Page PrintedPagePosition="2" PDFPagePosition="2" IsColor="False" />
                <Ghost PrintedPagePosition="3" PDFPagePosition="3" MayBePrinted="Unprinted" IsColor="False" />
                <Page PrintedPagePosition="4" PDFPagePosition="4" IsColor="False" />
                <Page PrintedPagePosition="5" PDFPagePosition="5" IsColor="True" />
</ColorPages>
```

I can easily deserialize this if I ignore the `Ghost` items, using these classes:

```
[XmlRoot("ColorPages")]
public class ColorPages
{
    public ColorPages() { Items = new List<Page>(); }
    [XmlElement("Page")]
    public List<Page> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [XmlAttribute("PDFPagePosition")]
    public string PDFPagePosition { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("IsColor")]
    public string IsColor { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I know I have to create a `BasePage` class that is the base class for both `Page` and `Ghost`, but I'm not sure how to make the deserializer handle this.

Comment: The deserializer will see the element name and instantiate the appropriate concrete class, Page or Ghost. `Items` though should be `List<BasePage>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[XmlRoot("ColorPages")]
public class ColorPages
{
    [XmlElement("Ghost")]
    List<Ghost> ghost{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Page")]
    List<Page> page{ get; set; }
}
[XmlRoot("Ghost")]
public class Ghost
{

}
[XmlRoot("Page")]
public class Page
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great!